# Login Failed for Host\Servername$

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2014, iis-8, application-pool

I have an API that is hosting on IIS 7.5. The application pool is configured use a domain service account. Then, I grant the account full permission on the default site.

The API and the database are on different server.

I create a SQL Server login for the account and associate it with a user. The user is granted db_onwer to the database. SQL Server service is configured to run using that service account as well. However, The API can't connect to the database. The database log shows this error message "Login failed for user host\servername$. If host\servername$ is given access to the server, it would work fine. However, IT said no way.

Majority of the solutions that I have found online so far either gave permission to host\servername$ to the database or change the apppool to use network or local service, or use a username and password where the username is not a domain account user.

I have to use a domain name account, so I am struggling to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the way the domain account was created. IT had to create another  service account. Once I set up the app pool with the new server account, I had no issue.